Issue signing a transaction with ethereumjs-tx
I have been trying to sign this transaction but it shows an error code repeatedly. Trying to sign a transaction in the Ethereum mainnet.
Code:
import { Web3 } from "web3";
import { Transaction, TxData } from "ethereumjs-tx";

const hashTx = (hash: TxData): Transaction => {
  const tx = new Transaction(hash);
  return tx;
};

const web3 = new Web3(walletProvider); // walletProvider from the web3 modal
const gasPrice: bigint = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
const gasLimit: bigint = 22000n;
const txFee: bigint = BigInt(Math.floor(Number(gasPrice) * 1.666));
const funds: bigint = BigInt(10000000000n - txFee * gasLimit);
const chainId: bigint = await web3.eth.getChainId();

const tx_ = {
  // from: target,
  to: host,
  nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce1),
  gasLimit: 0x55f0, // gasLimit
  gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(txFee),
  value: web3.utils.toHex(1000000000000n),
  data: "0x",
  v: "0x1",
  r: "0x",
  s: "0x",
};

const tx: Transaction = hashTx(tx_);

Error:
transaction.js:310 Uncaught (in promise) 
Error: Incompatible EIP155-based V 1 and chain id 1. See the second parameter of the Transaction constructor to set the chain id.
    at Transaction._validateV (transaction.js:310:19)
    at new Transaction (transaction.js:138:14)
    at hashTx

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?
I want it to sign a transaction so I can sign it with web3.js. I need it hashed so I can later serialize it.

The error explain what is wrong, it says that you need to check the second argument to new Transaction(hash);  you only have one argument. Also, the package is deprecated https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-tx it seems that it was replaced with @ethereumjs/tx.

Yeah... Noticed it a while back. Thank you for pointing out. Then I learnt that I may have to change the transaction type from legacy to EIP 1559 transaction type to fit the current standard.
